# std::is_member_function_pointer not working for noexcept member functions

Tags: c++, c++17

I am having trouble with `std::is_member_function_pointer`. As far as I can tell, it's not working when given a `noexcept` member function. I cannot find anything in the standard declaring that it does not work for `noexcept` qualified member functions. Example of the problem:

```
#include <type_traits>

class A {
public:
    void member() noexcept { }
};

int main()
{
    // fails at compile time if A::member is a data member and not a function
    static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&A::member)>::value,
                  "A::member is not a member function."); 
}
```

It gives me the following error:

> member.cpp:11:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement
>         'std::is_member_function_pointer::value' "A::member is not a member function."
>       static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer::value,
>       ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error
>   generated.

If I remove the `noexcept` qualification it compiles as it should.

This has been tested on Debian Stretch, using clang 6.0 and libstdc++ 6.3.0
Am I missing something here? From what I can read, this *should* work.

Comment: Have you tried libcxx instead? Maybe just a bug in the implementation?

Comment: Works with gcc 8.2 and clang 7.

Comment: Also [works](https://godbolt.org/z/8KQ2p-) in clang 6.0 and `-stdlib=libc++`, and [also](https://godbolt.org/z/7NZ_2S) with `-stdlib=libstdc++`. No idea which library versions are used there though.

Comment: Well, interestingly enough, install libc++-dev and compiling with that didn't help, but it might be a very old version in the repo (3.5.2). It seems it only breaks when enabling c++17 though, in c++14 mode it works. It must be that my version of libstdc++ is not updated yet for the fact that in c++17 noexcept is part of the type system.

Comment: Well, according to the `-v` output, the only available library version is 7.3 (regardless of the `-stdlib` option): https://godbolt.org/z/k3PQjs

Comment: And also VS2017 (15.9.6) with the latest compiler installed and standard set to latest.

Comment: `noexcept` became part of the function _type_ in C++17, I'm guessing that clang 6 implemented that language change but libstdc++ 6.3 had not yet.

Comment: Well, it works in gcc 6.3, in c++17 mode, perhaps gcc hasn't updated for c++17 noexcept types and that's why it works. Either way, it's a bug, and my money's on gcc's c++ libraries.

Comment: I think this is a related bug: [Function pointer conversion with noexcept fails](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39008)

Comment: @P.W I think this is not even related, it's the same bug. It's why it works in gcc - because they have the same function type for noexcept (which is wrong), while clang does it correctly and then chokes on the broken libstdc++.

Comment: @MartijnOtto: There is no discussion on the bug report confirming that it is a bug. Should we wait for such confirmation before answering this question?

Comment: @P.W Isn't what clang does in that bugreport actually the correct way? With noexcept part of the type system those functions have a different signature, so you would _expect_ the assignment to fail. The bug is that gcc allows it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code [compiles on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/-Hy1VZ) - with and without `noexcept` on the member - with all of MSVC 2017, GCC 5.5, 6.x, 8.x , clang 5, 6, 7.

On my Debian Stretch (well, the corresponding [Devuan](http://devuan.org/) really) - I can reproduce the issue. Interestingly, compilation fails even if I switch to libc++.

So:

- This is not a bug in clang-6 in-and-of-itself
- This is not a libstdc++ 6.3.0 bug in-and-of-itself
- It might have something to do with the way things were configured/set up for Debian Stretch. I suggest bringing this up on the #debian channel on irc.freenode.net

Comment: My money is on compiler bug. Had it been the lib, a linker error would've jumped out of the box. 'static_assert' triggers compile time error which takes place before the linker is invoked.

Comment: @Red.Wave: The library becomes involved upon `#include`, not just via `ld`.

Comment: @DavisHerring r u sure? those names("libXXX...") just remind me of ".so" files(dynamic libs). the "#include" directive happens to be a pre-processor thing that takes place at early compile phase; way before link time when those libxxx things show up.

Comment: @Red.Wave: Very.  Do you think that `<type_traits>` is **not** part of the library?

Comment: @DavisHerring not the binary part. Is "libc++" not the binary part? Compiler switch might mark the corresponding header path too. but does it? If it does, then I shall step back.

Comment: @Red.Wave: `libc++` is the name for the whole standard library implementation, including the headers as well as (what eventually becomes) `libc++.so`.  I don’t know what compiler *switch* you mean.